# MySQL Fieldtype for long numbers

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

If I set a field in MySQL table as `INT` so the number I store in it would remove all zero's.
For example, if I have an Id like this 100007431431552 finally it would be saved as 17431431552.
The field options are `INT` with length 32. So what's the problem?

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are storing FB IDs, use `varchar(20)` instead.

Comment: Only a value of 0007 woud cast to an int as 7, removing the 0's, 10007 will remain 10007 ;)

Comment: ok, I see the problem that INT is storing a maximum value for 2147483647 and min. for -2147483647. I have "BIGINT" now, but for the optimization I thought could optimize more for speed.  
So it would be better to stored theese ID's in VARCHAR 20 als BIGINT in consideration of speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`100007431431552` is too large for an `INT`.

If you were running in strict mode you'd get an error (`Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'id'`).

Unfortunately MySQL's default behaviour is to avoid any error messages and trying to do something else instead - at the cost of losing data without telling you (that's why `17431431552` stored in your example).

For this kind of values you need to use a `bigint`:

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19505/1

Comment: @onbids: you should really configure your MySQL installation to run with strict mode (and ANSI mode) to disable some of the stupid default behaviour (like truncating data instead of throwing an error). See the manual for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynindex-sqlmode.html

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL manual says the biggest value for an INT type are 2147483647 (signed) and 4294967295 (unsigned). The maximum values vor a BIGINT type are 9223372036854775807 (signed) and 18446744073709551615 (unsigned). So you should use a BIGINT column type.

Answer (score 1):

from [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

```
Type    Storage Minimum Value   Maximum Value
    (Bytes) (Signed/Unsigned)   Signed/Unsigned)
TINYINT 1   -128    127
        0   255
SMALLINT    2   -32768  32767
        0   65535
MEDIUMINT   3   -8388608    8388607
        0   16777215
INT 4   -2147483648 2147483647
        0   4294967295
BIGINT  8   -9223372036854775808    9223372036854775807
        0   18446744073709551615
```

you can not stroe so large number with `INT TYPE`.